# Colon in URL while redirecting?

Tags: java, web-applications, salesforce, urlencode, apex

I have a URL as below.

```
http://editor-sandbox.multiscreensite.com/home/dashboard?stat:339716385fb44bffae0d915cece952b8&dm_sso=2!eyJ2ZXJz
```

here the url has colon in it (:)

Now I am redirecting the URL as below.

```
pageRef= new PageReference(aboveURL);
                pageRef.setRedirect(true);      
                return pageRef;
```

But in browser, it is removing all the url params and final URL in the browser is :

```
http://editor-sandbox.multiscreensite.com/home/dashboard
```

How can I retain all the values in the URL including colon?

Answer (score 1):

Colon is a reserved character in URLs (see RFC 3986).  Whenever there is a chance that values may have reserved characters, you should urlencode it (this will replace `:` with `%3A`, `!` with `%21`, and others if any):

```
url = 'http://editor-sandbox.multiscreensite.com/home/dashboard?'
    + EncodingUtil.urlEncode('stat:339716385fb44bffae0d915cece952b8,'UTF-8')
    + '&dm_sso='
    + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(2!eyJ2ZXJz','UTF-8');
```